# How multimeters measure current in this circuit?

Tags: current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCzYu5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the circuit shown if current is flowing from negative side of battery to positive side
how multimeter can know the existence of resistor before electrons in wire hits the resistor?

I mean how multimeter measures current before it reaches the resistor? How it knows that a resistor exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meter is only measuring the amount of charge per unit time that is passing through its internal shunt resistance.  It doesn't know or care that there is a resistor in the way.

Your resistor is just limiting the current (charge/second) that the voltage source can "push" through the meter.  Think of a water meter measuring water flow.  If you put a kink in the hose upstream, the water flow slows down and the meter measures less flow.